# General solution to $ty' = Ay + b(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the general solution to the system $ty' = Ay + b(t)$ where $A$ is a constant matrix and $b(t)$ is a continuous function.

I know that given a system in the form $y' = Ay + b(t)$, the particular solution is written as $y_p = Y(t)\int Y^{-1}(t)b(t)dt$ where $Y(t)$ is a matrix whose ith column is the ith linearly independent solution to the system $y' = Ay$. Then the general solution to $y' = Ay + b(t)$ is written as $$y(t) = y_c(t) + y_p(t)$$

For $ty'(t) = Ay(t) + b(t)$, I am not sure how dividing by $t$ on both sides affects the particular solution if at all. If I divide by $t$, I get $y'(t) = Ay(t)\frac{1}{t} + b(t)\frac{1}{t}$, could I simply relabel $y(t)$ and $b(t)$ to include the $\frac{1}{t}$ term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow one of the strategies for Euler-Cauchy equations. Set $t=e^s$, $u(s)=y(e^s)$, then
$$
u'(s)=e^sy'(e^s)=Ay(e^s)+b(e^s)=Au(s)+b(e^s)
$$
which is now a usual linear system with constant matrix $A$.

Comment: @Isham and then I would solve for the corresponding particular solution? And LutzL, thank you.

Comment: What exactly is $\ln y$ or $(\ln y)'=\frac{y'}y$ when $y$ is a vector? And how does that compute with the matrix valued right side? By abuse of notation you could say that $t^A$ is a fundamental solution, but that is as far as simple analogies to the scalar case go.

Comment: Thanks @Lutzl it's abuse of notation indeed

Comment: Why is writing $ln(y)$ abuse of notation when $y$ is a vector?

Comment: No, abuse of notation is if some notation is used slightly outside its usual definition, but with some easy way to correct it. However, how would you define $\ln y$ for a vector $y$? And make it compatible with the homogeneous equation $ty'=Ay$?

Comment: @Nalt Lutzl is right..there is a matrix  $(A $ or $ \frac A t$ ) on the right side...on the left side we have $(\ln y)'$